# Learning inheritance | TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Attempting to inherit from **Superclass** `BasicToken`  to **Subclass** `StableCoin`

The value of `supply` is not being inherited by the **Subclass**: `StableCoin`

Can someone explain why?

```
class BasicToken:

    asset_class = "Crypto-Currency"

    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol


class StableCoin(BasicToken):
    def __init__(self, color, supply):
        self.color = color
        self.supply = supply

icon = BasicToken('icx')
icxStable = StableCoin('DMM', ['Blue', 'White'])

print('Icon Symbol: '+ icon.symbol)
print('IcxStable Symbol: '+ icxStable.symbol)
```

The `Error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Samson/Documents/PythonCourse-master/Section_04/assignment_04.py", line 30, in <module>
    print('IcxStable Symbol: '+ icxStable.symbol)
AttributeError: 'StableCoin' object has no attribute 'symbol'
```

Comment: You need to call constructor of super class in constructor of child. [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to init of StableCoin

```
class StableCoin(BasicToken):
    def __init__(self, symbol, color, supply):
        super(StableCoin, self).__init__(symbol)
        self.color = color
        self.supply = supply
```

If you are using PY3, calling super is easier `super().__init__(symbol)`. Though above works too.

Coming to your approach, your understanding seems a little incorrect. icon is an instance of BasicToken, and icxStable is a separate object which is an instance of StableCoin. They are not related.

Example, say we have class Mammal with property age, and another class Human(Mammal) with additional property "height", it is like constructing `blue_whale_whaley=Mammal(age=4)` and `chuck_norris=Human(height=180)` and then understanding that chuck_norris.age is blue_whale.age, which it is not as these are 2 different objects. To construct chuck_norris properly would be `chuck_norris=Human(age=50, height=180)`